# list all column names

Tags: mysql

select * from tbl

Is there an easy way to list all the column names from the table that will look like this?

select colA, colB, colC from tbl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by listing the column names. As already mentioned to list the data within all columns you'll need to write:

```
select * from table
```

Whereas if you'd like a list of just the columns in your table, give these a try:

```
show columns from table
```

or

```
describe table
```

More information on the latter can be found here

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/describe.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm completely sure what you mean by "list". To select all the columns you could do

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
```

or if you want list all of the columns and their types you can use

```
DESCRIBE tbl
```