# How to get a list of a table's field names?

Tags: mysql

If MySQL were rationally designed, I would be able to select from a describe table operation's results.

But that doesn't seem to work. So how can I get a list of a table's field names?

Comment: Please show the output/result of what you would like to accomplish.

Comment: There is nothing irrational about MySql design. It is simply different than you may be accustomed to (MS SqlServer, for instance). It just takes some getting used to ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [list all column names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803770/list-all-column-names)

Comment: @David: The accepted answer provides both.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMNS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html) table.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE table_name = 'YourTableName'
```

Answer (score 1):

MySql DDL: "show fields in myTableName"

**Edit - as requested from comment:**
DDL (Data Definition Language):
In the MySql Administrator, open a Query Browser window and select your database. Then enter the command above. Results will provide:

> Field *(fieldname)*
>   Type   Null
>   *(allowed, yes or no)*
>   Key 
>   Default *(value)*
>   Extra *(auto_increment, etc.)*

Executing this statement in .Net can result in a DataTable with all of these values. If you only require one of the fields, then you need to use the more explicit DDL described by @Joe Stefanelli.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this

> select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='my_table' and TABLE_SCHEMA='my_database';